# IOException aparece todo el rato y no se como solucionarlo

Tags: java, archivo

este es mi codigo y me salta el catch con

> No se puede inicializar el stream

siempre, esta opcion de un menu me deberia de leer lo que he escrito anteriormente en un fichero de objetos y almacenarlo en un array

```
                try {

                    File f;
                    ObjectInputStream leer = null;
                    FileInputStream streamdentro = null;

                    try {

                        f = new File("fichero.dat");

                        if (f.exists()) {
                            streamdentro = new FileInputStream(f);
                            leer = new ObjectInputStream(streamdentro);

                            while (true) {

                                for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) v[i] = null;

                                almacenamos = (Ticket) leer.readObject();
                                System.out.println(almacenamos);
                                System.out.println();

                                if (almacenamos != null) {
                                    v[contadordos] = almacenamos;
                                    myticket = almacenamos;
                                    contadordos++;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }            
               }
```

Comment: ya probaste a usar un try con recursos?

Comment: Si pero sigue pasando lo mismo.

Comment: Por favor comparte tu código completo (no se ve el catch) y el detalle de la excepción (todo el stack trace con el mensaje concreto)

Comment: Hola buenas, no me ha dejado compartir todo el codigo ya que decia que no podia poner tanto, lo siento pero es mi primera publicacion como resuelvo esto para poder enseñarlo al completo?